# How to make a div to lay over the previous one?

Tags: css, html

Normally a div gets displayed after the previous one (like to the right of it, to the down of it or wherever depending on the context and the styles set to them). I need a div to get displayed over (in terms of Z-order) the previous like if it was not there. What styles should I set to the background and the foreground divs to make them to behave so?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use absolute positioning on the `div` elements.

Given the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first-div"></div>
    <div class="second-div"></div>
</div>
```

You'd use the following CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.first-div,
.second-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here's a [demo with color](http://jsfiddle.net/C34TL/). I've offset the second-div by 5 pixels in both directions in order to show that they are layered.

Comment: Well, this works, thanks. But ideally I would like the second div to get aligned to the right side of the container in my case and as far as I understand absolute position implies the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you were saying. What do you mean align to the right side of the container? Use `right: 0` instead of `left: 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Content of outer div here -->
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- Content of inner div here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And apply this CSS:

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  /**
   * change this and other CSS properties like left, right
   * to position the inner div relative to the outer div
   */
  top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a `position:absolute;` added to the `css` of required elements will do.